# Names of absorbing sub-structures

Tags: abstract-algebra, gre-exam

I was taking a math GRE and found a curious property in a question.

There exists subsets $M$ of Rings $R$ that are absorbing but are not ideals.

A prototypical example (the one from the exam) is if given two ideals $U,V$ the set

$$ U \dot V =  \lbrace u*v  \ u \in U, v \in V \rbrace$$

So naturally take $m \in UV$ take $d \in R$ then it follows $md \in UV$ but $U\dot V$ isn't closed under addition. What is the name of such structures? And are there any interesting theorems regarding them (say like the isomorphism theorems)? Does there exist a general classification of such structures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you are asking about subsets $S\subseteq R$ with the property
$$
  rs\in S\text{ for all }r\in R,\;s\in S\hspace{10mm}(1)
$$
Note that the addition operation on $R$ is irrelevant here. Looking only at the multiplication operation, $R$ is a semigroup. In fact a subset of a semigroup satisfying (1) is also called a [(semigroup) ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup#Subsemigroups_and_ideals). There are results about the structure of semigroups and their ideals; see [Green's relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_relations).